# Как добавить элементы в массив static const char *

Tags: c++, массивы, visual-studio-2015

В общем, есть массив и нужно в него подобавлять элементов. Вопрос:каким образом это осуществить?

```
static const char *payload_text[12];

payload_text[0] = "Date: Mon, 10 Nov 2018 21:54:29 +1100\r\n";
*payload_text[1] = "To: " TO_MAIL "\r\n";
*payload_text[2] = "From: " FROM_MAIL "\r\n";
*payload_text[3] = "Cc: " CC_MAIL "\r\n";
*payload_text[4] = "Message-ID: <dcd7cb36-11db-487a-9f3a-e652a9458efd@"
"rfcpedant.example.org>\r\n";
*payload_text[5] = "Subject: SMTP example message\r\n";
*payload_text[6] = "\r\n";
*payload_text[7] = su;
*payload_text[8] = "\r\n";
*payload_text[9] = "It could be a lot of lines, could be MIME encoded, whatever.\r\n";
*payload_text[10] = "Check RFC5322.\r\n";
*payload_text[11] = NULL;
```

Comment: Никак, размер массива невозможно изменить. Вместо массива лучше использовать `std::vector`.

Comment: Что значит "добавить"? У вас `payload_text[0] =` правильно написано, а вот дальше какая-то ерунда пошла. Почему вдруг в `*payload_text[1] = ...` появилась эта `*`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если речь идет об инициализации массива, то так:

```
static const char *payload_text[]={

"Date: Mon, 10 Nov 2018 21:54:29 +1100\r\n",
"To: " TO_MAIL "\r\n",
"From: " FROM_MAIL "\r\n",
"Cc: " CC_MAIL "\r\n",
"Message-ID: <dcd7cb36-11db-487a-9f3a-e652a9458efd@",
"rfcpedant.example.org>\r\n",
"Subject: SMTP example message\r\n",
"\r\n",
su,
"\r\n",
"It could be a lot of lines, could be MIME encoded, whatever.\r\n",
"Check RFC5322.\r\n",
nullptr};
```